# My money has been disppeared

Tags: transfer, swift

My parent in another country has attempted a transfer(swift) to my account in Germany, one month ago. Transfer document shows that my IBAN is correct, and my own name and address details are correct. Money was received to my account one month ago and the same time it sent bank to sender! because Bank believes during electronic transfer a digital mistake happened! and some part of my address wrote after my full name by uncertain process, of course transfer paper never show it!
Now after one month it does not send back to the sender account!
I and my parent have asked both banks for finding it, but both of them believe money must be in the other one!
Is any place like court or inspector general in bank centers to help us for finding money?

Comment: I would try to do a 3 way call with both banks at the same time and let them work it out.

Comment: It is not possible,because in Germany people can not speak international language! and these banks are located in 2 different country!

Comment: Then I guess you need a 4 way (conference) call so you can add an interpreter. :)

Answer (score 3):

The first thing is for both of you to raise formal complaints with your respective banks, requiring them to find your money.

You don't say what countries you are in.  But I would expect that there would be regulators who are in charge of banks, and who have set up an official complaints organization (an "ombudsman").  If your formal complaint gets nowhere, find out what the procedure is in your country for complaining to the regulator or their appointed ombudsman.

Comment: Thanks Simon, transfer was from turkey to Germany,postbank